# Telerik file upload control rendering issue

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, telerik

I have a Telerik file upload control.  it renders misaligned to the other items on the page.  How can I get the control to render left aligned?

Screenshot of rendered page:

[image]

The markup:

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="PleaseSelectAFileLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Please select a file." CssClass="ControlLabel"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="PleaseSelectAFileType" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Please select a file type." CssClass="ControlLabel"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold">File Type</div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 296px" colspan="2">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="EmployeeImportFormatDropDownList" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="200px" OnLoad="EmployeeImportFormatDropDownList_OnLoad"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EmployeeImportFormatDownloadLink" runat="server" Text="Download Template" OnClick="EmployeeImportFormatDownloadButton_OnClick" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold">File</div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="DataImportsRadAsyncUpload" MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" MaxFileInputsCount="1" Width="375px" AllowedFileExtensions=".csv" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="75px"></td>
                <td style="width: 296px">
                    <asp:Button ID="DataImportFileUploadImportButton" runat="server" Text="Import" OnClick="DataImportFileUploadImportButton_OnClick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="DataImportFileUploadCancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="DataImportUploadCancelButton_OnClick"/><br /><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DataImportMappingLink" runat="server" Text="Employee Data Import Mapping" PostBackUrl="../Company/ImportDataMapping.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: What is your controls version? What is your browser? If it is a new browser with an old version - try upgrading. Also, try removing the CSS you have on the page in case a global selector (e.g., input{padding: 20px} is causing this.

Comment: I have been talking to the Telerik people.  They have been able to confirm that it is a custom style that I have applied to the page.

Comment: well then, I hope you figure it out :)

Comment: @rdmptn if you are interested.  I tracked it down.  The Telerik control uses an un-ordered list (ul) to create the green dot beside the uploaded file.  In the master page, there was a style setting ul's to a width of 25 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked it down. The Telerik control uses an un-ordered list (ul) to create the green dot beside the uploaded file. In the master page, there was a style setting ul's to a width of 25 pixels.